# Nesting table within Angular table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Let me start by saying that I am definitely new to Angular, but I have done a bit of digging and haven't found anyone else trying to do this with quite the same restraints.

I am attempting to create a nested table with the outer table containing rows of information from a JSON object. Beneath each row in this outer table, I need to generate another table that contains information from a JSON object retrieved using information from the outer table row. The problem I have is making sure that the information in the inner table is different for each row within the outer table. Right now, I'm running into an issue where I get the information for each an outer row displayed in every inner row for a brief moment before my script cycles through to the next outer row and changes the information for every inner row until the script reaches the end of the outer rows.

I'm working from an online application, with no true database access, hence the need to grab the data needed for the table from a URL.

Here are my scripts:

```js
var projectApp = angular.module('projectEditor', []);
var parents = [];

projectApp.controller('ProjectController', [ '$scope', '$http',
function($scope, $http, msSvc) {
 $scope.isLoaded = false;
 $scope.loading = true;
 $scope.url = '/api/now/table/';
 $http.defaults.headers.common.Accept = "application/json";

 $scope.updatePrjList = function() {
  $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: $scope.url + "pm_project?sysparm_query=active=true^ORDERBYDESCend_date&sysparm_limit=5&sysparm_display_value=true"
 }).
  success( function(data, status) {
  $scope.loading = false;
  $scope.isLoaded = true;
  $scope.projects = data.result;
  //parents.length = $scope.projects.length;
  for (var i=0; i< $scope.projects.length; i++) {
   parents.push($scope.projects[i].sys_id);
   //console.log($scope.projects[i]);
  }
   $scope.updateMSList(parents);

 }).
  error( function(data, status) {
   $scope.projects = [{"number": "Error fetching projects list"}];
  });
  };


  $scope.updateMSList = function(msURL) {
   console.log("URL: " + msURL);
   for (var i=0; i< msURL.length; i++) {
       
   $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: $scope.url + "pm_project_task?sysparm_query=active=true^ORDERBYDESCend_date^parent=" + msURL[i] + "&sysparm_limit=5&sysparm_display_value=true"
   }).
   success( function(data, status) {
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.isLoaded = true;
    $scope.milestones = data.result;
    var i;
    var l = $scope.milestones.length;
    for (i=0; i< l; i++) {
     //console.log($scope.milestones[i]);
    }
   }).
   error( function(data, status) {
    $scope.milestones = [{"number": "Error fetching milestones list"}];
   });
  }
  };
  $scope.updatePrjList();

 }] );
 });
```

```html
<div class="container col-md-12" ng-app="projectEditor">
        <div class="row" ng-controller="ProjectController">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="normal-cell col-md-1">Project</th>
                            <th class="normal-cell col-md-1">#</th>
                            <th class="normal-cell col-md-1">Percent Complete</th>
                            <th class="normal-cell col-md-1">Project Manager</th>
                            <th class="normal-cell col-md-1">Requestor</th>
                            <th class="normal-cell col-md-1">Portal/Application</th>
                            <th class="normal-cell col-md-1">State</th>
                            <th class="normal-cell col-md-1">Project Health</th>
                            <th class="normal-cell col-md-1">Target Date</th>
                            <th class="normal-cell col-md-1">Committed Date</th>
                            <th class="normal-cell col-md-1">Planned Impl. Date</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody ng-show="isLoaded">
                        <tr ng-repeat="proj in projects">
                            <td colspan="12">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="normal-cell col-md-1"><a class="project-link" href="pm_project.do?sys_id={{proj.sys_id}}" style="color: #91b4c5; font-weight: 600;">{{proj.number}}</a><div>{{proj.short_description}}</div></td>
                                        <td class="normal-cell col-md-1">{{proj.u_ranking}}</td>
                                        <td class="normal-cell col-md-1"><pct-complete value="proj.percent_complete"></pct-complete></td>
                                        <td class="normal-cell col-md-1">Test PM</td>
                                        <td class="normal-cell col-md-1">Test Requester</td>
                                        <td class="normal-cell col-md-1">Test Portal</td>
                                        <td class="normal-cell col-md-1">{{proj.state}}</td>
                                        <td class="normal-cell col-md-1">{{proj.u_health}}</td>
                                        <td class="normal-cell col-md-1">Test Target</td>
                                        <td class="normal-cell col-md-1">Test Commit</td>
                                        <td class="normal-cell col-md-1">{{proj.start_date}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                    <table class="table table-striped col-md-12">
                                      <thead>
          <tr>
           <th class="col-md-6 text-center">Project Description</th>
           <th class="col-md-3 text-center">Milestone Name</th>
           <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Planned Finish</th>
           <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Actual Finish</th>
           <th class="col-md-1 text-center">Status</th>
          </tr>
                                      </thead>
          <tr ng-repeat="ms in milestones">
                                          <td class="col-md-6">{{proj.description}}</td>
                                          <td class="col-md-3">{{ms.short_description}}</td>
                                          <td class="col-md-1">{{ms.start_date}}</td>
                                          <td class="col-md-1">{{ms.end_date}}</td>
                                          <td class="col-md-1">{{ms.state}}</td>
          </tr>
                                    </table>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: try this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pixic/sd5318kL/

Comment: I'm not sure from description if I understand if correctly but if Yea I faced with something similar in angular. My full code can be found on https://github.com/melnikovic/hierarchy-table-angular  Is this what you are looking for?  If yea I can provide more deeper explenation. 

p.s. Code above from @Rakeschand can be easier for you if you know number of max nested rows

Comment: As far as layout, I'm looking more for something like the table shown here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ej3WU.png

Comment: Hi Antonio. Can you please expose your output json object with values?

Comment: I can't expose it directly, but here are pastebins of my Project list: http://pastebin.com/rYRRGLwS and an example of a JSON object on the Task/Milestone level: http://pastebin.com/JuLQpiEQ